# Prolog binary tree using var(X)

Tags: prolog

I built the binary tree structure, binarytree(Data,LeftSub,RightSub).

```
istree(nil).
istree(binarytree(_,L,R)) :- istree(L), istree(R).
```

However, I want to represent empty tree by uninstantiated variable instead of istree(nil), using built-in predicate var(X).

```
istree(D) :- var(D).
istree(binarytree(D,_,_)) :- var(D).
istree(binarytree(D,L,R)) :- not(var(D)).
istree(binarytree(D,L,R)) :- not(var(D)), istree(L), istree(R).
```

I tried but it doesn't seem right.

Comment: Ideally, the meaning of a Prolog predicate should be given only by its set of ground (variable free) solutions. Otherwise, your program is simply a procedural artefact.

Comment: *I tried but it doesn't seem right.* What specifically did you try that doesn't seem right? If you remove the 2nd and 3rd clauses, and change `not(var(D))` to `nonvar(D)` it seems to be a suitable solution to your needs assuming you do want an uninstantiated variable, on its own, to be considered a valid binary tree (`istree(X)` will succeed for any uninstantiated variable `X`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asserting both the trueness and falseness of a set of clauses can be problematic. I think you can state only the positive cases, and let Prolog fail otherwise:

```
istree(T) :-
    nonvar(T),
    T = t(_,L,R),
    (var(L) ; istree(L)),
    (var(R) ; istree(R)).
```

I shortened the functor, to ease test

```
8 ?- istree(t(a,_,_)).
true 
.

9 ?- istree(t(a,t(b,_,_),_)).
true 
.

10 ?- istree(t(a,t(b,_,_),t(c,_,_))).
true 
.
```